# Ruby on rails 6: unable to edit my credentials.yml.enc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get add to my credentials.yml.
I have run

`EDITOR="sublime --wait" rails credentials:edit`

and

`EDITOR="subl --wait" rails credentials:edit`

which both returned:

`File encrypted and saved.`

but neither opened the decrypted file in Sublime text editor.

This is new to me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Will it open with `$ EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`?

Comment: Thank you, that worked a charm. Once I realised it wasn't an issue with the file, I ran it through Atom instead which worked fine; ```EDITOR="atom --wait" rails credentials:edit```

Comment: I had the same issue with VS Code and vim worked. Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

If `rails credentials:edit` does not open an editor to enable you to interactively edit the credentials but returns immediately with `File encrypted and saved.`, the 3 most likely issues are:

1. Your default EDITOR does not exist
2. You did not have default EDITOR set
3. Your default EDITOR forks upon launch, resulting in the `rails credentials:edit` returning upon fork

To cover all the issues describe:

1. Confirm that you have the editor of choice with `which <editor>`, e.g.:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

2. Call `rails credentials:edit` with EDITOR, e.g.,: `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`
3. If you still have issues, then check how your editor can avoid forking or add a wait to it. E.g.

```
# For sublime
EDITOR="subl --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit

# For vscode, which may required (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line)
EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit.

# For atom
EDITOR="atom --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit.
```